# Amchart error with the baseInterval set as month

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I trying to use amchart setting

```
dateAxis.baseInterval = {         
    "timeUnit": "month", 
    "count": 1 
}
```

But i have an error to show the data, when i have more than one day in the month with data, the graph show more than one bullet for the same  month.

for example if I have the next data

```
2019-10-11 => 20
2019-10-12 => 30
```

in place to display

```
(2019-10) => 50
```

the graph  show the next data

```
(2019-10) => 20, 
(2019-10) => 30
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmCharts v4 doesn't aggregate your data for you. `baseInterval` merely tells the chart how to render your data with the minimum intervals between your points. Setting it to month with multiple data points in the same month will display multiple points; this is as designed.

If you intend to display your data in monthly intervals and have some data points where more than one point is in the same month, you need to manually aggregate your data beforehand - in your case, convert that point to a single data item in October with a value of 50.

Comment: Thanks you very much!